# Cucumber - Feature File - nothing shows up in editor

Tags: eclipse, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have an issue with cucumber feature file. when I try to create a file without plugin - Im able to see the content in editor. Once I install the Cucumber eclipse plugin, Im not able to see anything in the editor - Its just blank screen. Please let me know if Im missing something here - Thanks

Eclipse Version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

---

[EclipseVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUgA7.png)

[CucumberEclipsePlugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7hUJ.png)

[Nothing shows up in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak6Xo.png)

Comment: Do any errors show up in Eclipse's logs?

Comment: Hi Pyves -  I dont see any errors in the log. Thanks